# what doest "hit or miss" in morphology do?

Tags: image-processing, morphology

I searched for hit or miss on the internet and Gonzalez's book but there is just a formula and example. In that example the hit or miss just finds a pixel and no more answers. I want to know by concept what is use and purpose of hit or miss transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Hit-or-Miss transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-or-miss_transform) as the name suggest uses 2 structuring elements (SE) to identify structures which are specific to the foreground (first SE) and background (second SE).

[Here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hitmiss.htm), you have a good example for corner detection. The only difference is that the two SE are merged into 1: The 1 are part of the foreground SE in order to determine a specific shape in the pattern, and the 0 are part of the background SE. Consequently, the algorithm hits only if all the conditions on the 1 and 0 are respected, else it's a miss.

This principle is mainly used for skeleton computation, but it can be derived to build all the mathematical morphology basic operations.

Here are more explanations:
 - [A complete video of a class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b87PK29j9m0).
 - [Much more examples in this complete lesson](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/notes/hit-or-miss.pdf).
 - [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609869/hit-and-miss-transform-in-image-processing)